# Mapstruct version 1.2.0.Final not converting embedded types?

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

After working through the [mapstruct tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) I was under the impression that Mapstruct did correctly convert embedded types. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. any advice would be greatly appreciated...

I am working in IntelliJ 2017, with the Mapstruct plug-in installed. the failing tests included state that the embedded object, in this case, the job object inside the jobData object, is null:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected: is not null
>        but: was null
>   Expected :is not null

Actual   :null

the following code is the source, destination, mapper interface and impl, and tests that fail. one thing that is interesting is that the impls do not have a reference to calling the converter for the embedded types.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobData {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Job job;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    private String providerName;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobDataDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private JobDTO jobDTO;
    private String providerName;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class JobDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private JobState jobState;
    private Date creationDateTime;
}

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Job {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private JobState jobState;

    @NotNull
    private Date creationDateTime;
}


@Mapper
public interface JobDataMapper {
    JobDataMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(JobDataMapper.class);
    JobDataDTO jobDataToJobDataDTO(JobData jobData);
    JobData jobDataDTOToJobData(JobDataDTO jobData);
    JobDTO jobToJobDTO(Job job);
    Job jobDTOToJob(JobDTO jobDTO);

}

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2018-03-24T16:33:39-0600",
    comments = "version: 1.2.0.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class JobDataMapperImpl implements JobDataMapper {

    @Override
    public JobDataDTO jobDataToJobDataDTO(JobData jobData) {
        if ( jobData == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        JobDataDTO jobDataDTO = new JobDataDTO();

        jobDataDTO.setId( jobData.getId() );
        jobDataDTO.setProviderName( jobData.getProviderName() );

        return jobDataDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public JobData jobDataDTOToJobData(JobDataDTO jobData) {
        if ( jobData == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        JobData jobData1 = new JobData();

        jobData1.setId( jobData.getId() );
        jobData1.setProviderName( jobData.getProviderName() );

        return jobData1;
    }

    @Override
    public JobDTO jobToJobDTO(Job job) {
        if ( job == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        JobDTO jobDTO = new JobDTO();

        jobDTO.setId( job.getId() );
        jobDTO.setJobState( job.getJobState() );
        jobDTO.setCreationDateTime( job.getCreationDateTime() );

        return jobDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public Job jobDTOToJob(JobDTO jobDTO) {
        if ( jobDTO == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Job job = new Job();

        job.setId( jobDTO.getId() );
        job.setJobState( jobDTO.getJobState() );
        job.setCreationDateTime( jobDTO.getCreationDateTime() );

        return job;
    }
}

public class JobDataMapperTest {

    private static final long TEST_LONG = 1L;
    private static final String TEST_STRING = "CUSTOMER";
    private static final Date TEST_DATE = new Date();

    private JobDataMapper jobDataMapper = JobDataMapper.INSTANCE;

    private Job job;
    private JobData jobData;

    private JobDTO jobDTO;
    private JobDataDTO jobDataDTO;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        job = new Job();
        jobDTO = new JobDTO();

        jobData = new JobData();
        jobDataDTO = new JobDataDTO();
    }

    @Test
    public void jobDataToJobDataDTO_EmbeddedJobDTODataConversion() {
        jobData.setId(TEST_LONG);

        job.setId(TEST_LONG);

        jobData.setJob(job);

        jobDataDTO = jobDataMapper.jobDataToJobDataDTO(jobData);

        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getId(), is(instanceOf(Long.class)));
        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getId(), is(TEST_LONG));

        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getJobDTO(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getJobDTO(), is(instanceOf(JobDTO.class)));
        assertThat(jobDataDTO.getJobDTO().getId(), is(TEST_LONG));

    }

    @Test
    public void jobDataDTOToJobData_EmbeddedJobDTODataConversion() {
        jobDataDTO.setId(TEST_LONG);

        jobDTO.setId(TEST_LONG);

        jobDataDTO.setJobDTO(jobDTO);

        jobData = jobDataMapper.jobDataDTOToJobData(jobDataDTO);

        assertThat(jobData.getId(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(jobData.getId(), is(instanceOf(Long.class)));
        assertThat(jobData.getId(), is(TEST_LONG));

        assertThat(jobData.getJob(), is(notNullValue()));
        assertThat(jobData.getJob(), is(instanceOf(JobDTO.class)));
        assertThat(jobData.getJob().getId(), is(TEST_LONG));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your logs? You should have some warnings about unmapped target properties (`job` and `jobDTO`). You would need to tell MapStruct how to map them by using `@Mapping`.

You mapper should look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface JobDataMapper {
    JobDataMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(JobDataMapper.class);
    JobDataDTO jobDataToJobDataDTO(JobData jobData);
    JobData jobDataDTOToJobData(JobDataDTO jobData);

    @InheritInverseMapping
    JobDTO jobToJobDTO(Job job);

    @Mapping(target = "job", source = "jobDTO")
    Job jobDTOToJob(JobDTO jobDTO);
}
```

With `@Mapping(target = "job", source = "jobDTO")` you are telling MapStruct that it needs to map `jobDTO` into `job`. With `@InheritInverseMapping` you are saying inherit all the inverse configuration (i.e. `@Mapping(target = "jobDTO", source = "job")`).

You can also enable [`ReportingPolicy#ERROR`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/ReportingPolicy.html#ERROR) that would fail the build in case there is an unmapped target property by using `@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)`